# Order of operations when adding dereferenced pointers

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, char

I'm given these lines of code in c and asked to explain its output:

```
char  str [50] = "hello \0 worl\bd";
printf("\n %s ",str);
printf("%s \n",str+str[4]-*str);
```

Output:

```
 hello   word
```

From my understanding the second line prints the string until the '\0' character which indicates the end.
The third code then adds the rest of the string (from the space befor the 'w' skipping the 'l' as it is overwritten by the backspace.

What I don't understand is what exactly happens in the expression:

```
str+str[4]-*str
```

Doesn't the expression get executed like this:

1. Add pointers to first element of char array: str+str
2. Increment the resulting pointer by 4 and dereference it (Which should return a character?)
3. Subtract the character that *char returns from the character from 2.?

It seems like thats not what happens. Can somebody explain to me what exactly happens here?
Thanks alot!

Comment: The expression becomes `str + 'o' - 'h'` which, for a standard ascii codepage is `str + 111 - 104`, and therefore `str + 7`. That answer, btw, could be different on a codepage different than ascii, such as ibm-ebcdic, where it would `str + 14`

Comment: @WhozCraig And we don't know how the display media handles a backspace character.  ***BAD*** question.

Comment: Well, in defense of the question. I was given the code and told to run it myself and then explain the output. So I was not given the output and also it's a preperation question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
char  str [50] = "hello \0 worl\bd";
```

the code

```
str+str[4]-*str
```

evaluates to

```
str + 'o' - 'h'
```

because `str[4]` is the character `'o'` and `*str` is the character `'h'`.

Note that the result of adding (or subtracting) an integer-type value from a pointer is another pointer value.

But we don't know what the *values* of `'o'` and `'h'` are because the question doesn't specify the character set.

If we make the unstated assumption that the character set is ASCII, the character `'o'` is the integer value `111`, and `'h'` has the integer value `104`, so the value is

```
str + 111 - 104
```

(But see @dbush's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65971357/4756299) as `str + 111 - 104` is evaluated as `( str + 111 ) - 104` and `str + 111` invokes undefined behavior as it's well past the end of the `str` array)

or

```
str + 7
```

so it's the address of the seventh character in `str` - `&str[7]`:

```
printf("\n %s ",str);
```

will emit

```
"\n hello "
```

without the quotes (the quotes are used to display the trailing space), and

```
printf("%s \n",str+str[4]-*str);
```

is

```
printf( "%s \n" str + 7 );
```

and will emit

```
" worl\bd \n"
```

again without the quotes.  But the `'\b'` is the backspace character, so you'll likely see

```
" word \n"
```

printed on your screen - probably.

But there are assumptions in the question that prevent anyone from definitively stating what will be output:

- the character set may not be ASCII, in which case the program likely invokes undefined behavior
- the display media may not process the backspace character as expected

Without that information, the question can not be answered.

Precision matters in C.  Questions like this that do not precisely specify the conditions and environment necessary to be able to answer the question are horrible and poorly thought out.

Comment: Even if the character set **is** ASCII, the C specification makes no guarantee that any character's integer value, other than `['0'-'9']`, falls in any particular order. Never run into this myself, but an interesting fact.

Comment: A better question would involve the use of numerals, and then `str[x] - '0'` which is portable across all coding sets.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Very easy to understand

Comment: @Oka Absolutely true.  And you will run into the problem of non-sequential alphabetic characters on IBM mainframes, which are still around.  But if we do assume ASCII, the values of all characters are specified. I'm assuming the person writing the question made that assumption.

Comment: @AndrewHenle the calculation of `str + 'o' - 'h'` is guaranteed to be *exactly* as shown here if the precondition of Oka's statement is true; i.e. "if the character set is ASCII". Those values are formally defined for that codepage per a standard outside of C, and at that point it's simple math. Only when you cannot assert the codepage origin, as mentioned in the first caveat bullet of the summary here, does that calculation become a free-for-all. In short, this answer is accurate as-is.

Answer (score 4):

In this expression:

```
str+str[4]-*str
```

The array subscript operator `[]` has the highest precedence, followed by the dereference operator `*`, followed by `+` and `-` which have the same precedence and group left to right.  So the above is the same as:

```
(str+(str[4]))-(*str)
```

So what happens is that the array `str` is converted to a pointer to its first element, then the character code for `str[4]` is added to that pointer, then the character code for `*str` (or equivalently `str[0]`) is subtracted from that.

Substituting in the characters in question, the above is the same as:

```
(str + 'o') - 'h'
```

Which, assuming ASCII encoding, is the same as:

```
(str + 111) - 104
```

**But now we have a problem.**

The subexpression `str + 111` creates a pointer that is well past the end of the array, and doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so your program is not well formed.  It doesn't matter the the next operation would seem to give you a valid pointer.  Just *creating* the pointer value `str + 111` is invalid.

This is described in section 6.5.6p8 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding pointer addition/subtraction:

> When  an  expression  that  has  integer  type  is  added  to  or  subtracted  from  a  pointer,  the result has the type of the pointer operand.  If the pointer operand points to an element o fan array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression. ... If  both  the  pointer operand  and  the  result  point  to  elements  of  the  same  array  object,  or  one  past  the  last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So you're "lucky" that the program is generating output that, from a quick look, would appear to be expected.

Had it been written like this:

```
str+(str[4]-*str)
```

The program would be well formed.

Comment: The voice of reason. I completely forgot about pa overreach. Given the proper boundaries and segmented architecture, this could easily bit someone's arse.

Comment: Yes indeed.  I missed it too.

Answer (score 3):

```
str[4]='o' // 111 in ascii
*str='h'   // 104 in ascii

str+str[4]-*str= str+111-104=&str[7] => ' worl\bd'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't think about values of characters.